# Disable merging of CSS/JS in registry.xml in Plone

Tags: javascript, css, merge, registry, plone

Is it possible to disable merging of a CSS/JS File in css/js registry.xml in Plone?

Something like that:

```
  <javascript id="++my++theme/javascripts/myscript.js" 
            mergeble="False"
  />
```

It's possible to enable/disable caching and other options in e.g. cssregistry.xml with cacheable="False" or so. But is there a way to disable merging? In the Plone documentation is nothing about that..

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

OK, it's hardly intuitive, but the option you're looking for is "cookable=false". See http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/javascript.html#registering-javascripts-to-portal-javascripts

You could also have done that through the ZMI (http://yoursite.example.org/portal_css/manage_cssForm), where the option is more obvious, and then export the registry XML from the portal_setup tool. That way you get to see exactly the correct syntax.

Comment: @Leonardo Thanks for the edit. That link must have been broken for years, now.